# How to get <td> value in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've done some code in html and in JavaScript ... My query is when I click on `<td>`, whatever the value associated with it, has to be displayed in the corresponding text box ... 
In front of `<td>` I've taken the textbox ... for an example I've taken 3 `<td>` and 3 textboxes

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
       function click3(x) {
       x = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML
       var a = document.getElementById("txt"); 
       a.value = x; 
       }
       function click1(y) {
       y = document.getElementById("addr").innerHTML
       var b = document.getElementById("txt1");
       b.value = y;
       }
       function click2(z) {
       z = document.getElementById("email").innerHTML
       var c = document.getElementById("txt2");
       c.value = z;
         }
       </script>
```

this is my JavaScript code , I know this is not an adequate way to deal such problem, since its giving static way to deal with this problem 
does anyone have a better solution for this problem ??
In JavaScript/jQuery

Comment: provide us with your html structure

Answer (score 1):

If click1, click2 and click3 are supposed to be three event then you have to keep all three function you can shorted the script code for assigning values to text field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function click3(x) {
      document.getElementById("txt").value = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
   }
   function click1(y) {
     document.getElementById("txt1").value = document.getElementById("addr").innerHTML;
   }
   function click2(z) {
     document.getElementById("txt2").value = document.getElementById("email").innerHTML; 
   }
   </script>
```

You can make a single function if you have single click event and shorten the code for assignment like this,

```
function SomeClick(x) {
   document.getElementById("txt").value = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
   document.getElementById("txt1").value = document.getElementById("addr").innerHTML;
   document.getElementById("txt2").value = document.getElementById("email").innerHTML;    
 }
```

Comment: A single click should set all 3 values??? That sure doesn't sound like what the question describes.

Comment: Well .. Seems like You've misunderstood my question ... after adding  your code I encountered this problem when I click on a <td> it is giving me the values of all <td>s ... I don't want that ....  it has to be on specific click ....

Comment: If you put the html you have then it may bring some good solution.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your question, you could try the following, assuming that's how your HTML is structured:

**HTML Markup**:

```
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
     <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Tom</td>
    <td class="addr">789</td>
    <td class="email">tom@dot.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Dick</td>
    <td class="addr">456</td>
    <td class="email">dick@dot.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Harry</td>
    <td class="addr">123</td>
    <td class="email">harry@dot.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input id="txt1" type="text" />
<input id="txt2" type="text" />
<input id="txt3" type="text" />​
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(".name").click(function(){
   $("#txt1").val($(this).text());
   $("#txt2").val($(this).nextAll().eq(0).text());
   $("#txt3").val($(this).nextAll().eq(1).text());
});​

$(".addr").click(function(){
   $("#txt2").val($(this).text());
   $("#txt1").val($(this).prevAll().eq(0).text());
   $("#txt3").val($(this).nextAll().eq(0).text());
});

$(".email").click(function(){
   $("#txt3").val($(this).text());
   $("#txt2").val($(this).prevAll().eq(0).text());
   $("#txt1").val($(this).prevAll().eq(1).text());
});
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9weS/

Answer (score 0):

You can combine columns and rows. Per cell consisting id you give it th column title and

number of series it could be the index of the row combination of row and column gives the

address as per table cell by a specific event you can read the value of the id

Then you know to pull the cell value.

```
 $('tr')
        .click(function() {
        ROW = $(this)
            .attr('id');
        $('#display_Colume_Raw')
            .html(COLUME + ROW);

        $('#input' + COLUME + ROW)
            .show();
        STATUS = $("#input" + COLUME + ROW)
            .val();
    });
```